# wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated()) with @FindBy?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Why does this work?

```
public void mymethod(){
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(by.id("myid"));
}
```

And this doesn't work?  I don't understand.

```
@FindBy (id="myid")
WebElement myid;

public mypagefactory(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver);
}

public void mymethod(){
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated((By) myid));
}
```

I keep getting an "invalid cast" error on the "(By)".  I'm trying to use the page factory methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `invisibilityOfElementLocated` is expecting a locator of type `By`, but you are providing the proxied `WebElement`. Use `invisibilityOfAllElements` instead:

```java
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(Arrays.asList(myid)));
```

Comment: Now that I see your solution that makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast a WebElement to By, but it's not a By element, it's WebElement.

by.id("myid") returns By, so there's no problem.

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
@FindBy (id="myid")
WebElement myid;
```

is an equivalent of

```
By by = By.id("myid");
WebElement myid = driver.findElement(by);
```

As you see `myid` is of type `WebElement` in both cases (annotation does not convert it into object of type `By`), while casting from `WebElement` to `By` is not possible, since they are [not sharing the same class hierarchy](http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/type-casting-java-implicit-explicit-casting/).

Answer (score 0):

My solution when I ran into needing the By locator to use for an ExpectedConditions and I had my locators in the Page Object Factory was to use a String that had the locator in it and then build my By object and the element locator from that.

```
public class PageObject(){
    private static final String ID = "myid";

    public @FindBy (id=ID)
    WebElement myid;

    public By getByID(){
        return new By.ById(ID);
    }

    public PageObject(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver);
    }
}
```

```
public void mymethod(){
    By by = getByID();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(by);
}
```